# Loop through SQL code with different parameters (Presto)

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I'm working with Presto/Trino.

I need to run the same SQL query several times, but each time with different inputs.

The SQL code consists of several chained CTEs that analyze data based on one date and number of weeks, so the query will analyze data based on that date and the number of weeks of data before that date.

The structure would be:

```
dates = [date1, date2, date3, ...]

number_weeks = 4 #I might modify this number sometimes

for date in dates:
     {
     SELECT with several CTEs with SQL using `date` and `number_weeks`
     }
```

I could make a UNION of the SQL output of each iteration to have all the results in one output.

Is this possible in Presto?

Answer (score 0):

If one output is okay, then you do not need loop or union, just use filter

```
...WHERE date in (date1, date2, date3, ...)
```

Comment: the `date` is not a condition, it's an input. The CTEs will make calculations based on the input date and return many rows with different KPIs based on that specific date. The calculation needs to be repeated for each date.